# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$center_name

Tags: php, laravel

Hi following are my relations

SchoolsList.php

```
public function requisitions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Requisition::class);
}
```

Requisition.php

```
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

My Blade

```
<td>{{ dd($requisition->schools()->center_name) }}</td>
```

I Get this error.

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$center_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$requisition->schools() it is instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo`, but $requisition->schools is instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

```
@if ($requisition->schools) // or $requisition->school
   <td>{{ $requisition->schools->center_name }}</td>
   // or <td>{{ $requisition->school->center_name }}</td> // corrected relation
@endif
```

One advise if if your relation is belongsTo use `single` relation name

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to do this:

> $requisition->schools()->first()->center_name

This will give you center_name of the school the requisition belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`<td>{{ dd($requisition->schools->center_name) }}</td>`

if you get the this error : `Trying to get property of non-object` problem is in your relation , check the database column name, the column name of database must:

for the `schools table`: you should have the `requisition_id` in table `requisitions`.
check laravel relation convention in here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to optimise this and not having problems with datatables, for example, do it like that :

```
<td>{{ ($requisition->schools) ? $requisition->schools->center_name : "" }}</td>
```